# phpmyadminをcakephpで使えるようにする

Tags: phpmyadmin

どなたかご協力頂けますと幸いです。

現在、cakephpにphpmyadminをインストールして、 
cakephpのDBを閲覧、変更できるようにしたいです。

検索したのですが、これといった参考になる記事がなく困っております。

一応下記の記事を参考に

１、phpmyadminの最新verをローカルにDL 
２、phpmyadminというディレクトリを/var/www/html配下に作成 
３、所有者をappachに変更 chown -R apache /var/www/html/phpmyadmin 
４、[http://IPアドレス/phpmyadmin/でアクセス](http://IP%E3%82%A2%E3%83%89%E3%83%AC%E3%82%B9/phpmyadmin/%E3%81%A7%E3%82%A2%E3%82%AF%E3%82%BB%E3%82%B9) 
５．404エラーの表示

となってしまいます。

https://www.conoha.jp/conoben/archives/9304

大変御手数をおかけ致しますが、 
こちらアドバイス頂けますと幸いです。

現在サーバー情報として 
・mysql 5.7.10 
・linux 3.10 
・php 7.0.2 
・centos7.2

となります。

※追記 
etc/httpd/conf/httpd.confの下記は

DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"

となっております。

Comment: 参考サイトの手順で進められたと思いますが、404エラーとのことなので、１）ディレクトリ名に間違いがないか、２）ダウンロードしたphpmyadmin一式がちゃんと/var/www/html/phpmyadmin以下に展開されているか再度確認してみてください。

Comment: https://teratail.com/questions/41707 マルチポスト

Answer (score 1):

大文字小文字を間違えている可能性があります。

ディレクトリ名にもし大文字が入っている場合、例えば phpMyAdmin となっている場合は
[http://IPアドレス/phpmyadmin/](http://IP%E3%82%A2%E3%83%89%E3%83%AC%E3%82%B9/phpmyadmin/)
ではなく
[http://IPアドレス/phpMyAdmin/](http://IP%E3%82%A2%E3%83%89%E3%83%AC%E3%82%B9/phpMyAdmin/)
でアクセスしてみてください。

Comment: ありがとうございます。
上記試してみましたが、エラー状況に変化がありませんでした。